# Detecting a kill request in a Windows service with dotnet core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, service, kill

I have created a Windows service on dotnet core 3.1 using the class BackgroundService.

Is there a way to detect a kill request that was sent e.g. via the task manager, with taskkill or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic steps in the command prompt for you to follow:

1 - Find out the Service Name

2 - Find out the PID of the service

```
   sc queryex servicename
```

3 - Kill the PID

```
    taskkill /f /pid [PID]
```

You can read [more](https://support.4it.com.au/article/how-to-kill-a-windows-service-which-is-stuck-at-stopping/).